# Sed script needed to insert LF before each time match in a large single string

Tags: awk, sed

I have lengthy string that I need to put a line feed before each instance of a time stamp.

```
03:38:11,03/07/2017,node,cpu,user,sys,idle,intr/s,ctxt/s,0,0,0,9,91,0,1,0,24,75,0,total,0,17,83,2370,3574,1,0,3,4,
93,1,1,10,4,86,1,total,7,4,89,2922,4653,03:39:11,03/07/2017,node,cpu,user,sys,idle,intr/s,ctxt/s,0,0,4,25,71,0,1,5
,16,79,0,total,4,21,75,2487,3876,1,0,0,3,97,1,1,1,1,98,1,total,1,2,98,2880,4728,03:40:11,03/07/2017,node,cpu,user,
sys,idle,intr/s,ctxt/s,0,0,1,30,69,0,1,1,30,69,0,total,1,30,69,3237,4344,1,0,3,49,47,1,1,10,47,43,1,total,6,48,45,
3920,5702,
```

I need to see about formatting it as such:

```
03:38:11,03/07/2017,node,cpu,user,sys,idle,intr/s,ctxt/s,0,0,0,9,91,0,1,0,24,75,0,total,0,17,83,2370,3574,1,0,3,4,93,1,1,10,4,86,1,total,7,4,89,2922,4653,

03:39:11,03/07/2017,node,cpu,user,sys,idle,intr/s,ctxt/s,0,0,4,25,71,0,1,5,16,79,0,total,4,21,75,2487,3876,1,0,0,3,97,1,1,1,1,98,1,total,1,2,98,2880,4728,

03:40:11,03/07/2017,node,cpu,user,sys,idle,intr/s,ctxt/s,0,0,1,30,69,0,1,1,30,69,0,total,1,30,69,3237,4344,1,0,3,49,47,1,1,10,47,43,1,total,6,48,45,3920,5702,
```

I am currently trying to use the following:

```
sed -e 's/^[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]\:[[:digit:]][[:digit:]]/\n&/g' cpu.log
```

Comment: I should also note that it does put a LF in on the first match, but not subsequent matches.

Comment: `sed -E 's/,([[:digit:]][[:digit:]]:)/,\n\1/g' cpu.log` may be

Answer (score 0):

The `^` line anchor forces `sed` to only match the first date stamp. Remove it and you should be fine.

To *avoid* roplacing the first, maybe massage the script to require something before the match (hard-coding a comma would seem to work, based on your sample data); or just post-process the output to remove the first newline.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/\n&/g'
```